# How to uninstall jupyter in Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This question have been asked a handful of times but none of the answers I have found have helped me at all.

I installed `jupyter` in my local Python 2.7 enviroment. Then installed Anaconda3 to run Python 3.6 and because the Conda distribution supports some packages I could not install locally via `pip`.

However the existing Python 2.7 `jupyter` installation is clashing with the Anaconda one. As I mentioned do not seem to be able uninstall `jupyter` via any of the methods I could find, and `pip uninstall jupyter` simply outputs `Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed`.

How can I uninstal `jupyter` so only the Anaconda one exists in my machine?

Comment: did you clean the path environment variable?

Comment: @rachidelkedmiri the one at `c:\python27\scripts`? No I didn't because then I can't run `pip` or other packages I may need to use.